# DocuSign Embed Send Moment Timezone Error

Tags: docusignapi

Occasionally when I attempt to use the [embed edit](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createEdit/) option in Windows Edge or Internet Explorer I get the following error:

```
Moment Timezone found undefined from the Intl api, but did not have that data loaded.
vendor.bundle-94bd639c.js (297,3398)
```

This results in the user being redirected to their DocuSign home page rather than the envelope they are attempting to edit.  Is there anyway to work around this?

Comment: I'm sorry you're having this problem. Can you create a repeatable problem?

Comment: I haven't been able to yet, no.  It typically happens if I have more than one tab of DocuSign open, but not always.  I've been trying to find the recipe to replicate but haven't been able to.